# Segmentation fault w/ EQU and no errors with DB?

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

The program I wrote is very simple. You have to type a number and the computer checks if it is the number '6'. So guessing the number basically.

Testing the program, I found that there was a Segmentation fault. The fault was fixed and program works fine now. But I don't really understand why. About 10 minutes of googling and nothing turned up so I decided to ask here.

The following code snippet is the one that caused the segfault (in section data)

```
guessnum equ 6
```

And after making it this:

```
guessnum db '6'
```

The code worked!

Here's the compare block if it matters:

```
xor al, al  ; clearing the al reg
mov al, [num] ; moving the value that num points to into al reg
cmp al, [guessnum] ; the actual compare

jz success  ; jumping to the successful guess label if the user guessed right
```

Thank you.

(Am under Linux if it helps.)

Comment: Instead of googling you should try the nasm manual next time. `equ` only defines a constant and does not allocate storage. As such your code ended up being `cmp al, [6]` instead of `cmp al, [some_memory_with_content_6]` that you wanted. Learn to use a debugger. Also `6` and `'6'` are different things (the latter is the ascii code, 54 decimal). The `equ` version (with the fixed ascii value) would have worked if you had written `cmp al, guessnum` (no brackets) as that would have used immediate not a memory address.

Comment: I'm using "edb-debugger" built from sources on github, for small asm examples it's sufficient for me (for large projects it may be still lacking with support for multithread and debug info, I'm not sure, as I don't care about those). In GNU world the "gdb" is used basically everywhere and for everything, but it's command line based debugger, so you may want to search for some "UI" built over it (although if you will invest lot of time into learning controlling bare gdb, you will have basic skill for any GNU environment). Check also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more resources.

Comment: You may also try to go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly questions and see what common problems are and how to resolve them.